# Tangent makes with the x-axis

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

A curve has equation $y=\frac{4}{3x-4}$ and $P$(2,2) is a point on the curve.  Find the angle that this tangent makes with the x-axis.

Can anyone explain this ?

Answer (score 1):

The angle is related to the slope of the tangent line at the point. Specifically, the slope is given by the derivative:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
y' & = \left( \frac{4}{3x - 4} \right)' |_{x=2}\\
   & = -\frac{12}{(3x -4)^2} |_{x=2}\\
   & = -3
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
which means $\tan \theta = -3$, so $\theta = \tan^{-1} (-3)$ is your angle.

Comment: Answer is $\tan^{-1}\pm (-3)$ why?

Comment: Printing error.

Comment: @Mathxx Perhaps the problem does not specify to which direction of the $x$-axis one counts the angle.